# OledDbDataAdapter "Syntax error in FROM clause" exception

Tags: c#, oledbdataadapter

I'm using OleDB to import data into grid from text file with extension ".K$$".

Here's some example code:

```
FileInfo file = new FileInfo(filename);
string connectionString = "";
OleDbDataAdapter adapter;
OleDbConnection con;

connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OleDb.4.0;Data Source=" + file.DirectoryName + ";Extended Properties=\"Text;Format=TabDelimited;\"";

con = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
con.Open();
adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(String.Format("SELECT * FROM {0} ", file.Name), con);

adapter.Fill(MyDataTable);
```

when executing the Fill method it throws the exception. What's wrong with the FROM clause? Thanks

---

EDIT:

Ok, after some tests I found out that the problem is with the "$" symbols. Maybe it's some reserved symbol ? 
Also, if I rename the extension to ".txt" the file got loaded into the grid but it only have 1 column , which means it can't see that there're tabs in the rows.

Another issue is that when I change the file extension to something different than ".txt" (for ex. ".tx") the Fill method throws exception "Cannot update. Database or object is read-only".

Comment: What is the exception? You should use a Try and Catch statement withthis also.

Comment: what is the value of `file.Name`?

Comment: The syntax all looks fine, it has to be with the connection string

Comment: @codingbiz the name of the file (not the full path name) plus the extension.

Comment: Does the path have spaces in it? Neither the directory nor the filename is escaped/quoted.

Comment: @DanielRenshaw the filename is  6328523.K$$

Comment: Print out the value of `String.Format("SELECT * FROM {0} ", file.Name)`. What about the special symbols???

Comment: @codingbiz the ouput is "SELECT * FROM 6328523.K$$"

Comment: I'm not familiar with this but I suspect `6328523.K$$`. Try select another file name that doesn't have all this funny symbols e.g. SomeData.TXT

Comment: can you please add the connection string in full.. so i can see teh exact string its building please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I just tried creating an example.K$$, and then tried to connect to it using the same provider as stated through Server Explorer in Visual Studio 2010. Its an Unrecognised format.

I don't think this will ever work.

You may need to look at connecting via a different provider or method.

I think You should look at this link :-

EDIT :

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6737/Fill-a-DataSet-from-delimited-text-files

It will allow you to read your txt file into a datable correctly.

Comment: No worries, I have to be honest, Your trying to read a txt file like a structured Database. I use OLE Data Adapters alot, with MS Access Databases. I'll do some researchand see if theres a solution for you.

Comment: Thanks for finding it. I don't have problem with .csv and excel files with the OleDB but I guess I'll have to make my own parser for the other text files.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking the path of the filename if its correct

Answer (score -1):

Check that neither the directory, nor the filename, contain spaces. If they do, you'll need to escape/quote them.

You'll also need to quote the filename if it contains an extension since the `.` is not a valid character in the `FROM` clause. Try `FROM [{0}]` (though this may not be the correct quoting character for the `OleDbDataAdapter`).

Comment: None of them is containing spaces.

Comment: @DimitarTsonev you'll still need to quote the filename because of the extension character. See my updated answer.